# Spring's @Autowired doesn't inject dependency

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a project that consists of various modules.
Basically, I've worked with Spring MVC & JUnit 4, and everything was working good.
But Now, I added few classes which aren't related to testing or MVC, and the @Autowired annotation doesn't inject objects to them.
The same objects are injected to the MVC and JUnit classes, so I realy confused.

This is the Spring Context XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.justic.more" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="monkDAO" class="com.justic.more.data.monkDAO" />
    <bean id="BidDAO" class="com.justic.more.data.BidDAO" />

</beans>
```

The Class that I want to inject to:

```
@Component
Public Class Tesser {

@Autowired
MonkDAO monkdao;

...
blablabla
...
}
```

Comment: Does MonkDAO component exist?

Comment: @skaffman, No, Just Null-pointer exception when I try to use the object, then I figure it wasn't injected.

Comment: If `@Autowired` cannot be satisfied, Spring throws an exception. You never get as far as a null. Are you sure you're not just doing `new Tesser()`, rather than letting Spring instantiate it?

Comment: Just a try... rename the property to monkDAO (matching case in conf file)

Comment: Ok, I just realized that probably the problem is with the ContextConfiguration. but here's the catch. I can't just put @ContextConfiguration in the classes because I have two of them, one for Testing (H2 database, Jetty, etc.) and one for "production"

Comment: @Paolo: `@Autowired` does type based injection. No need to rename the property.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using `Tesser`.

Comment: @CodeBrickie: I don't have more to add, all the rest is unrelevant methods which do validation. nothing special...

Comment: Really: Please show the code where you are calling a method in an instance of `Tesser`. Is it a test case? How's `Tesser` instantiated there?

Comment: @CodeBrickie: Yes, it's a testcase, and I just declare and run the default constructor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5389/discussion-between-mellowcandle-and-codebrickie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the chat with OP it became clear that he created the object like `Tesser tesser = new Tesser()` instead of injecting it into the test class. 
Spring has no chance to autowire dependencies in beans that it does not create itself.

The solution is to autowire the `Tesser` object into the test class so Spring can inject the dependencies.

```
@Autowired
private Tesser tesser;

@Test
public void testSth() {
    assertTrue(tesser.someBoolReturningMethodUtilizingMonkDAO());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 0):

Add qualifiers:

```
@Resource(name = "monkDAO")
```

If you start with annotations, go all the way.

Comment: How do you tell your test classes to read the Spring configuration?  Are you using @ContextConfiguration annotation?

Comment: oh, now you're talking... The JUnit is running with ContextConfiguration. The MVC doesn't need one, I don't know but probably it's scanned for @Controller annotation.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that probably the problem is with the ContextConfiguration. but here's the catch. I can't just put @ContextConfiguration in the classes because I have two of them, one for Testing (H2 database, Jetty, etc.) and one for "production"

Comment: Just use the "test" one for testing.